# How to send automatic email notification to user before two months expire date

Tags: sql-server

I had two columns in my database table in SQL Server i.e `start-date` and `expiry-date`. When user subscription going to end before two months where it needs to send automatic email to user regards your subscription going to end please renew subscription. how to write stored procedure in SQL Server

Comment: AFAIK sql can not send emails. One option how you could solve the task is: You chose you server side scripting language of choice. Then check those dates inside that script and then run that script via cronjob.

Comment: There is sp_send_dbmail (if its SQL Server) but I would recommend this process is externalized to the DB layer, a database shouldn't be the place you run this process. Please specify exactly which RDBMs this question is for.

Comment: using  sql  server. if there is any possibility please send me example.

Comment: SQL Server Agent Alerts...

Comment: Use SQL Server Agent to schedule a job to run every day and check for expiry. Use `sp_send_dbmail` to send any required emails. That's one solution

Comment: Use an Agent Task, and [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Without more information, we can't really give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. but can anybody give me example query for that ?

Comment: Why did anyone upvote this?

Answer (score 1):

To That You Need to Define A job which contains your business using SQL Server Agent Link Below :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Inside the Job you need to setup the email :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Here is Also tutorial step by Step : https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/send-query-results-sql-server-agent-job/.

The other main point should you do that ?
One of main concepts in software development is Separation of concerns. Where each layer is responsible  for doing specific thing and does it well.

So if your Project has another layers, notifications should be in another layer not in DB level as Mentioned by Andrew in the comments.